# Getting a 502 bad gateway error on nginx hosting

Tags: nginx, hosting

I'm getting a error in my hosting while trying to authenticate twitter and facebook.
I'm getting this error in the authentication success page.

### 502 bad gateway

nginx

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the error log to see why nginx is throwing a 502 error by adding

`error_log logs/error.log` to `nginx.conf`.

Then restart nginx and watch the log file with `tail -f logs/error.log` as you try to authenticate.

Comment: This is my server log.

Can anyone help me?

[Fri Oct 26 23:37:37 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sat Oct 27 00:00:41 2012] [error] [client 216.70.111.161] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/killioning.com/httpdocs/
[Sat Oct 27 01:21:43 2012] [error] [client 216.70.111.161] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/killioning.com/httpdocs/favicon.ico
[Sun Oct 28 00:05:53 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?